# mysql error 1054 : unknown column job_title

Tags: mysql

anyone can tell me why am i getting this error :

> error 1054 : Unknown column 'DEPARTMENT.department_name' in 'on clause'

which i dont really get it why

here is my code :

```
select EMPLOYEE.job_title ,EMPLOYEE.employee_id , EMPLOYEE.department_name 
from EMPLOYEE join (select EMPLOYEE.employee_id  
      from EMPLOYEE  
      group by    EMPLOYEE.employee_id 
      having count (distinct EMPLOYEE.department_name) >1)
  DEPARTMENT on  EMPLOYEE.department_name = DEPARTMENT.department_name;
```

Comment: May be there is no `job_title` column  in `DEPARTMENT` table

Comment: You only select `EMPLOYEE.employee_id` in your inner SQL, so your table `DEPARTMENT` which is the result of the inner SQL has only the column `employee_id`

Comment: @Jens what does that means ? even if i remove the EMPLOYEE.job_title and department_name it still give me unknown column department.department_name

Comment: This query doesn't make a whole lot of sense. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @user130875 `DEPARTMENT` is an alias of `select EMPLOYEE.employee_id  
      from EMPLOYEE  
      group by    EMPLOYEE.employee_id 
      having count (distinct EMPLOYEE.department_name) >1` right? So this result has only one column `employee_id `

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a typo error:

your query says:

```
MPLOYEE.department_name = DEPARTMENT.department_name;
```

should be:

```
EMPLOYEE.department_name = DEPARTMENT.department_name;
```

Comment: @Jens when there is no table then from where do we get the column name, MPLOYEE.department_name

Comment: If you have no table, you get an error message like "table or view does not exists"

Comment: @jens the question has been updated now by the user :)